# Merge 3 lists defined by 1 variable

Tags: python, list

I have a text (simplified):

a b c d

e f g

Then I have this code (MapReduce):

```py
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    words = line.strip().split()
    print(words)
```

The variable *words* gives me:

```py
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
[]
['e', 'f', 'g']
```

**How to get:**

```py
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create words variable as an empty **LIST** and just add the values in it. Refer the code below. Also, **print()** should be used outside the loop.

```
import sys
words = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    words += line.strip().split()
print(words)
```

**words** variable will be updated as this:

> words = [ ] + ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] + [ ] + ['e', 'f', 'g']

**Output:**

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

Comment: Thanks @abdeali004 but it still gives me 3 list on 3 different lines as follows:

```python 
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: Check the code. I think your print() is in the loop. Keep the print() outside while loop, as mentioned in my code.